# Does CruiseControl.NET support access to a repository via the http protocol?

Tags: svn, http, cruisecontrol.net, config, ccnet-config

I am trying to set up cc.net on the project I'm working on at the minute. I have done this before using a config containing lines like these:

and
svn://svn.mycompany.com/myfirstproject/trunk

However this time I only have read only access to the repository via HTTP as opposed to via svn. Will the same config work with the trunkUrl set to the http address? do i need a different config? will it work at all?

I am finding it difficult to find any help online and don't really want to go through the hassle of setting up the build server to test configs if it isn't going to work anyway!

Any help/ideas would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will work just fine - behind the scenes CruiseControl.Net uses svn.exe - and svn is quite capable of checking out a repository from a read-only http repository.

If in doubt, simply try doing `svn co http://svn-server/path/to/svn/repos` on the command line of the cruise control server (using the appropriate svn authentication username/password) - if that works, cruisecontrol will work.